# Can a calibrated prediction model that is able to discriminate have a poor Brier score?

Tags: logistic, predictive-models, auc, calibration, scoring-rules

I did a logistic regression with selected covariates on a dataset with about 10000 records and event rate of 10%. The cross validated c-index was 63% which admittedly is not very high. Looking at a calibration plot the model seemed well calibrated. However, the reduction in Brier score from a model without covariates was only about 3%. What can be the cause of the low reduction in Brier score?

A random forest on the same data gave a c-index of 59% and still a low reduction in Brier score compared to the logistic regression without covariates.

Comment: I think the issue at hand here is how you are defining "low".  Why do you say that a 3% reduction in brier score is "low", and a 63% c-index is "not very high"?  These measurements are meant to be *comparative*, not absolute.  Its possible that your data just does not support any better predictive power, and your models are doing the best the data can bear.

Comment: Admittedly I don't have much experience with c-indexes and Brier scores reported in the literature, but naively I feel a 3% reduction in Brier score is low. With this thinking I would conclude that the model with covariates does not have good predictive power compared with a model without any covariates. Are you saying that the size of the reduction in Brier score is not a good measure predictive power?

Comment: No, I'm saying something different, that there is no *absolute* measure of predictive power.  Only comparative statements like "model A has more predictive power than model B for predicting phenomena P" are meaningful.  The c-index and brier score are red-herrings, this is true for any measure of model predictive power.  If you only have one model, there is no scientific meaning to low and high predictive power.

Comment: @MatthewDrury It seems like you have a good sense of how to answer this question. Perhaps you could collect these comments into an answer?

Comment: @MatthewDrury: do you want to post your comment(s) as an answer? [Better to have a short answer than no answer at all.](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5326/1352) Anyone who has a better answer can post it.